# Duplicated content shown in a view using a relationship

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I am using a view that has a contextual filter ("Content: Has taxonomy term ID") and a relationship ("Content: Taxonomy terms on node"); for some reason, I keep getting duplicated content. In the view settings I have "Distinct" checked.

Are there any other options I can look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Check if one of your fields have multiple values, like Taxonomy Terms, or Images. Then, you have to group those values with the according option to prevent this.